# Getting Items for Likert

Tags: r

I'm trying to get a likert scale out of my data frame,
but only the summary works, which means I have no items, to plot and analyse it further?!
[image: Data for Likert Scale]

This is basically my data in a `data.frame`
when I use

`likert <- likert(summary = likertModel)`

I get Basically this model out of it.

[image: Likert Results]

Is it possible to add the items?
These should be get and post?

To create the `data.frame` I'm filtering times from a `.csv`

```
 verylow <- length(filter(csvData, between(Latency, 0, 12000))$Latency)
  low <- length(filter(csvData, between(Latency, 12001, 24000))$Latency)
  mid <- length(filter(csvData, between(Latency, 24001, 36000))$Latency)
  high <- length(filter(csvData, between(Latency, 36001, 48000))$Latency)
  veryhigh <- length(filter(csvData, between(Latency, 48001, 60000))$Latency)
  return(data.frame("verylow" = verylow, "low" = low, "mid" = mid, "high" = high, "veryhigh" = veryhigh))
```

Thanks!

Edit:
libraries.

```
require(likert)
library(dplyr)
```

input data csv:

```
    timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,URL,Latency,IdleTime,Connect
1615550905818,5100,GetRequest,200,OK,172.31.0.3-ThreadGroup1 1-620,text,true,,233,164,1000,1000,http://traefik_reverse-proxy_1/dashboard,5100,0,6
1615550905810,5109,GetRequest,200,OK,172.31.0.3-ThreadGroup1 1-608,text,true,,233,164,1000,1000,http://traefik_reverse-proxy_1/dashboard,5109,0,0
1615550905827,5093,GetRequest,200,OK,172.31.0.3-ThreadGroup1 1-319,text,true,,233,164,1000,1000,http://traefik_reverse-proxy_1/dashboard,5093,0,0
1615550905827,5102,GetRequest,200,OK,172.31.0.3-ThreadGroup1 1-408,text,true,,233,164,999,999,http://traefik_reverse-proxy_1/dashboard,5102,0,1
1615550905827,5102,GetRequest,200,OK,172.31.0.3-ThreadGroup1 1-726,text,true,,233,164,999,999,http://traefik_reverse-proxy_1/dashboard,5102,0,1
1615550905810,5119,GetRequest,200,OK,172.31.0.3-ThreadGroup1 1-680,text,true,,233,164,999,999,http://traefik_reverse-proxy_1/dashboard,5119,0,0
1615550905828,5112,GetRequest,200,OK,172.31.0.3-ThreadGroup1 1-75,text,true,,233,164,996,996,http://traefik_reverse-proxy_1/dashboard,5112,0,1
1615550905829,5111,GetRequest,200,OK,172.31.0.3-ThreadGroup1 1-112,text,true,,233,164,996,996,http://traefik_reverse-proxy_1/dashboard,5111,0,1
1615550905829,5120,GetRequest,200,OK,172.31.0.3-ThreadGroup1 1-597,text,true,,233,164,995,995,http://traefik_reverse-proxy_1/dashboard,5120,0,2
```

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thanks will fix it when i get home! Could take its time, as I'm new to R

Comment: Also specify what packages you are using. There are multiple versions of the `filter` and `between` functions.